# Prevent content to be duplicated when clicking multiple times with Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an extension to this question [How to get value from nested HTML tag with Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618325/how-to-get-value-from-nested-html-tag-with-jquery-javascript)

When I execute the following script after the first time, the `<h2>`-tags get duplicated multiple, though I only want the three values displayed...

so my question is, what is going wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.submit').on('click', function () {

       $('#newLoanDiv').append('<div id="test"></div>');
       $('.results-page').contents().appendTo($('#test'));

       setTimeout( function(){ 
          $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
          $('.sums').find('dl').each(function () {    
              $('<h2 class="value">' + $(this).find('dd').text() + '</h2>').insertBefore('#test');
          });
       }, 100 );
    });

});
```

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Try `$('#test').empty();` to clear data of the `#test` on every click.

```
$('.submit').on('click', function () {
   $('#newLoanDiv').append('<div id="test"></div>');
   $('#test').empty();
   $('.results-page').contents().appendTo($('#test'));

   setTimeout( function(){ 
      $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.sums').find('dl').each(function () {    
          $('<h2 class="value">' + $(this).find('dd').text() + '</h2>').insertBefore('#test');
      });
   }, 100 );
});
```

Comment: Hmm, good suggestion, but I need to click the button as many times as I want... :-/

Comment: I added `$('#test').empty();` try this.